# Hero_id and villain_id coming up as nil after creating and saving the object, nested route can't navigate to correct path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, associations, nested-routes

I set up a controller alert to alert me when the index or show routes come back nil when trying to route to them i.e. I click on the link_to link for hero involved "Thor" and receive this error.

What I am trying to accomplish eventually is to try to nest these routes together so all heroes and eventually villains will be associated and nested within the report routes and users will eventually be able to enter a new hero if it's not there already. However, it doesn't seem to be assigning a hero_id or villain_id. However, it does assign the user_id of the user that submitted the report.

I suspect it has something to with my associations being off or not correctly synced up, but I could be wrong.

[image: Error]

Hero Controller

```
def index
    if params[:report_id]
        @report = Report.find_by(id: params[:report_id])
        if @report.nil?
            redirect_to reports_path, alert: "Report not found"
        else
            @heros = @reports.heros
        end
    else
        @heros = Hero.all
    end
end

def show
    if params[:report_id]
        @report = Report.find_by(id: params[:report_id])
        @hero = @report.heros.find_by(id: params[:id])
            if @hero.nil?
                flash[:notice] = "Hero not found"
                redirect_to report_hero_path(@report)
            end
    else
        @hero = Hero.find(params[:id])
    end
end

def create
    @hero = Hero.build(hero_params)
    if @hero.save
        flash[:notice] = "Hero was successfully created"
        redirect_to @hero
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def hero_params
    params.require(:hero).permit(:hero_name)
end
```

Report Controller Params

```
def report_params
    #byebug
    params.require(:report).permit(:subject, :description, :hero_ids, :villain_ids)
end
```

Report Model

```
class Report < ApplicationRecord
   validates :subject, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6, maximum: 100 }
   validates :description, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10, maximum: 300 }

   belongs_to :user
   
   has_many :report_heros
   has_many :heros, through: :report_heros

   has_many :report_villains
   has_many :villains, through: :report_villains
end
```

Hero Model

```
class Hero < ApplicationRecord
    validates :hero_name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 25 }
    validates_uniqueness_of :hero_name
    
    has_many :report_heros
    has_many :reports, through: :report_heros, dependent: :destroy

end
```

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks' }, 
              skip: [:mailer, :unlocks, :passwords, :confirmations]  
  resources :users, except: :new

  resources :reports do
    resources :heros, only: [:index, :new, :show]
  end
  
  resources :heros
  resources :villains

  
  get 'about', to: 'pages#about'

  root 'pages#home'
end
```

Index for Reports

```
<div class="container">
   <h1 class="row justify-content-center">Report Index</h1>
   <table class="table table-bordered bg-light">
      <thead bgcolor="#959595">
         <tr>
            <th scope="col">Subject</th>
            <th scope="col">Description</th>
            <th scope="col">Created By</th>
            <th scope="col">Hero Involved</th>
            <th scope="col">Villain Involved</th>
            <th scope="col">Edit</th>
            <th scope="col">Delete</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <% @reports.each do |report|%>
         <tr>
            <td><%= report.subject %></td>
            <td><%= report.description %></td>
            <td><%= link_to report.user.email, report_path(report) %></td>
            <% report.heros.each do |hero|%>
            <td><%= link_to hero.hero_name, report_heros_path(:hero_id, :report_id)  %></td>
            <% end %>
            <% report.villains.each do |villain|%>
            <td><%= villain.villain_name %></td>
            <% end %>
            <% if report.user == current_user %>
            <td><%= link_to "Edit Report", edit_report_path(report) %></td>
            <td><%= link_to "Delete Report", report_path(report), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %></td>
            <% end %>
         </tr>
         <% end %>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <%= link_to 'New Report', new_report_path, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show your index.html code or can I have your repo?

Comment: added the index.html.erb for reports

Comment: Thank you, I see, is it possible to post the log of the request with error you have encounter?